# USING SSIS to check a file for words in the name

Tags: ssis

I'm trying to use SSIS to check if a file contains the words _nodata

If it does, I want to end the package execution. I have used script to check if there are files in a folder, but I can't figure out how to see if the file contains certain words. Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried searching how to read contents of a file? You would need to write a c# script to do this.

Comment: do you have multiple files at source location ?

Comment: I currently use a vb script to check if the files exist. but now I need to no if any of the file have _NoData in the name of the file only. I dont' need to look in the file itself. Any idea how to do that ?

Comment: on some days, (like Monday after a weekend) there could be multiple files. most days there is only one file. However, on the days where the occorruence _noData is in the name, is usually after a weekend.

Comment: I think, correct me if I'm wrong, I can create a precedence to check the value of a variable (which is the file name). And if it contains the words _noData to send an email..... just need help to manipulate the variable for those words, and if can be done in a precedence constraint

Comment: i was thinking on the same lines . use foreach loop to loop the files in the folder. Then check if the file name contains that word using  precedence constraint and control the package  execution.

Comment: I am trying to do the by using the precedence Expression and constraint and value success and expression right(@v_filename,11) =="No Data.csv" doesn't seem to working. Is the expression right? Or have I done something wrong?

Comment: By the way, I already have a for each loop set up. It can capture multiple files in the folder. I want to make sure that I get all the files and archive properly

Comment: Also, I had the package email me with that expression right(@v_filename,11)  and it does send me NO Data.csv, exactly what I'm looking for. but the precedence constraint won't execute that properly....

Comment: Just looking at the expression which looks at the variable @v_filename for a file name which ends in "No Data.csv" eg right(@v_filename,11) =="No Data.csv".  If l have understood you are looking for files ending "_nodata.csv"? So should the expression be right(@v_filename,11) =="_nodata.csv"?

Answer (score 0):

In your VB Script task, you can use the `FileSystemObject` to access the name of the file.   I assume you are already using the `FileSystemObject` because you say you are checking to see if the file exists.

Read up on the `FileSystemObject` in MSDN to see all the properties it exposes, and learn how to access the file name and see if it contains "_nodata".